# Link several controls to share one event

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, textbox, gps

[image: emt]
The Textbox that is to the right of the word message has to be updated by a text change event.The textbox for the event change is the one that currently has the 1234 Main St address.The problem arises when the other comboxes, textboxes and radio buttons are used instead of a street address to update the messageTextbox.  The data only shows if I go back to the addressTextbox and trigger the event change. Can I somehow link the all of the textboxes in the Emergency Location groupbox together so that as data is entered into any of them they cause the change event to fire.

Comment: question is too long and boring tell in precise way what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry to bore you but then I wouldnt be looking for help if it was an easy fix or easily explained.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, you want to ensure the textbox is not 'empty'?

```
private void textBoxAddress_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (streetRadioButton.Checked && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxAddress.Text) == false)
    {
         // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not so much a need to ensure the textbox is empty. Its all about updating another textbox as data is entered using the single text change event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea!

Step 1 Add all Event

Add all radio button select changed event for **"Emergency type"** Groupbox.

Add all radio button select changed event for **"Emergency Location"** Groupbox.

Add all combobox, and Textbox textchanged event.

Step2 Write a Function

Write a function with case statement. I think you need two case statement one for Emergency Type and one for Emergency location case statement suppose to get value from radio button.
In case statement you can populate the **"Message"**

Step 3
Call this function on each event.
I hope it will help

Comment: Add you can also add many control with one event like this button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click_1); button2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click_1);

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your idea is something I haven't tried, now I need to see if I can work it into the very strict framework my professor has given for this assignment.

Comment: Share the way how did you do it, May me your/professor way is better then mine.